# Declaring JavaScript Object property of a constructor object having arguments issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an object using constructor pattern and also define properties using Object.defineProperty.

```
function random (a,b,c) {
  var sample = null;
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  if(b && c){
   this.sample(b,c);        
  }
  Object.defineProperty(random, 'sample', {
   get: function(){
    console.log(b);
   }
  });
};

var foo = new random(10,1,2);
```

**This throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function.
What am I doing wrong ?** Please Help.

Comment: How are you *calling* the function?

Comment: you can't pass arguments to a getter

Comment: var caller = new random(1,2,3);

Comment: What is `this.cache`?

Comment: I removed arguments from getter but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You reference `sample` before it is defined
- You define `sample` on the constructor (`random`), but it should be on `this`.
- There was a closing parenthesis missing.
- You call `sample` like a function, but you had not defined it as one. The function in `defineProperty` is the getter, not the method itself. If you want to code it like this, you need the getter to return your method.

Check this corrected code with comments:

```js
function random (a,b,c) {
    var sample = null;
    
    this.a = a;

    // First define, then call:
    // Define on this, not on random:
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'sample', {
        get: function() {
            // must return a function
            return function (b) {
                console.log(b);
            };
        }
    }); // <-- missing bracket
    // Moved after defineProperty:
    if(b && c) {
        this.sample(b,c); // note that you don't use the second argument
    }
}

console.log(new random(1,2,3));
```

Comment: Did this answer suit your needs? Could you accept or leave a comment?